# Cost function for screening model considerring misclassifying of NSCLC and normal

Tags: function

How to determine the most suitable sensitivity and specificity for the lung cancer screening model, when we consider the cost functions when misclassification occurred. Any existed cost functions to FP and FN?

maybe such as binary logistic regression or SVM.

Thanks.